# Git Status not recognizing changes

Tags: git

Odd situation here.  I have modified several files, and for the sake of this discussion, SearchG2Helper.cs and SearchG2Helper.Custom.cs are definitely different but git status shows no differences.  I also checked `git check-ignore -v SearchG2Helper.Custom.cs` and that didnt respond with anything.

See the git internals command outputs below:

```
$ git cat-file -p 9b02b119
...snip...
100644 blob 231f4f6eebcb377fbb318845b8a2b17a7eb7732e    SearchG2Helper.Custom.cs
100644 blob 56dc73150a5c73ccba0d4d41c205caa8379c9314    SearchG2Helper.cs
100644 blob 6922412c3a1954367f89b873188aa38a1a5ac4d5    _AssetExtensions.cs
100644 blob dbe562aede1287a2a42824a2c29fc15579df4b98    _CPContrib.AspxHelper,0.1.0,AspxHelper.cs
100644 blob c68060a2e13842a8fe3e1f559f484a0f53c5ca1e    _CPContrib.Core,0.2.0,Core.cs

$ git hash-object SearchG2Helper.cs
8bdd145719c3a8a6dd8cccf2185d3826d159b28e

$ git hash-object SearchG2Helper.Custom.cs
9f071c622d7896026c556cf2574b94778f58cec6
```

Notice that hash in the tree object is totally different from the hash given by `git hash-object`, yet, a `git status` doesnt show any changes

Using Git for Windows 2.15.2.1

Note, using git internal information understood from this url: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

*Update: A new Clone into a new directory seems to have fixed the issue.  I'm just wondering how this git database got corrupted? and what to look for?*

Comment: What is `9b02b119`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth 9b02b119 is the blobid for the tree object.  basically the object that represents the current directory.  I started with ```git cat-file -p master^{tree}``` and kept working from there.  Used info from: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: I cannot see enough above to identify any actual problem. However, note that what `git status` does is to (in effect) run *two* `git diff`s: one from the current (HEAD) commit to the contents of the index, and one from the contents of the index to the work-tree. More precisely, the second one compares what is in the index *now* to what *would* go into the index *if* you ran `git add` on a file. That second step applies any cleaning that would be directed by configuration files. Git will in some cases actually *skip* this second diff step if the time stamp and other information in [continued]

Comment: ... in the cache portion of an index entry matches the time stamp and other information in the file system, so as to speed up the index-vs-work-tree diff, which would otherwise be quite slow. If you adjust the cleaning rules (e.g., by changing end of line treatments for a file) without changing any file contents anywhere, you can change the hashes that are produced by running `git hash-object`, yet `git status` will believe the files are *already* "clean". So that might explain the issue.